# Have 4 GB of memory on 32-bit laptop running Ubuntu -- any way to use it?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, memory, 32-bit

I have 4 GB of memory on a 32-bit laptop (Lenovo T61, in case it matters) running Ubuntu 9.10. Is there any way to make use of it all?  Ubuntu only sees 3 GB, of course.  Is there any way I can utilize the last GB of memory?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should NOT use the server kernel unless you are running a server. To use all of your laptop's 4 GB install the [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) version of the generic kernel with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
```

Comment: Is there any downside to using `linux-image-generic-pae` over the "normal" kernel?  Thanks!

Comment: PAE makes memory access slightly slower. VERY slightly. Other than that, no.

Comment: is that a 32-bit kernel?  if so, thats cool.